# JQ: Populate json data using a json template

Tags: json, jq

I'd like to transform a "raw" json data transforming to other json structure.

For example:

```
def template:
{
  "id": "$id",
  "practitioner": "$practitioner",
  "patient": {
    "name": "$patientName",
    "familyName": "$patientFamilyName"
  }
}
;
```

My data.json is:

```
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "practitioner": {
      "practitionerKey1": "practitionerValue1",
      "practitionerKey2": "practitionerValue2"
    },
    "name": "John",
    "familyName": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "practitioner": {
      "practitionerKey1": "practitionerValue1",
      "practitionerKey2": "practitionerValue2"
    },
    "patientName": "Samuel",
    "patientFamilyName": "Schnaider"    
  }
]
```

My desired result would be:

```
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "practitioner": {
      "practitionerKey1": "practitionerValue1",
      "practitionerKey2": "practitionerValue2"
    },
    "patient": {
      "name": "John",
      "familyName": "Smith"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "practitioner": {
      "practitionerKey1": "practitionerValue1",
      "practitionerKey2": "practitionerValue2"
    },
    "patient": {
      "name": "Samuel",
      "familyName": "Schnaider"
    }
  }
]
```

Any ideas about how to map above data json and populate it using a json template with JQ?

Comment: Your template is flawed, the variables have no definitions. They should either be field names (`.id` instead of `$id` etc.) or you need parameters in the template def (e.g. `def template($id)`). Otherwise it's unclear how to apply the template.

Comment: Also, neither the content of your `data.json` input file nor your desired result is actually proper JSON. Not quoting field names is a shorthand in the `jq` language, but it's not JSON.

Comment: quotes solved. Ignore my template approach. I simple thought it could be achieved using those substituion. But I've no idea in fact......

Comment: @pmf - I think the OP wants the "$-strings" in the template to be replaced by the corresponding key names in the JSON.  That is an error-prone approach but it is do-able.

Comment: @Jordi - Your approach is error-prone. Have you looked at the section on "jq as a template engine" in the jq Cookbook?  (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#using-jq-as-a-template-engine)

Comment: Maybe a typo: The array's first object has keys `name` and `familyName`, the second has `patientName` and `patientFamilyName`. Both get transferred into `name` and `familyName` under `patient` in the output. I therefore presumed in my answer that the input array's first object is just misspelled here. Correct me if this is indeed intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding your template, why not simply calling

```sh
jq 'map(
  .patient = {name: .patientName, familyName: .patientFamilyName}
  | del(.patientName, .patientFamilyName)
)' data.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4lH1g9HaLO) (For this, I corrected your input JSON according to a presumed typo described in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69924653/jq-populate-json-data-using-a-json-template#comment123607303_69924653) above)

Comment: The problem is that my real template is very large and I'm only need to change those fields... I think is usefull use some kind of template.

Answer (score 0):

The "query-by-example" approach you envision in the question is do-able, though it is error-prone (and indeed as @pmf pointed out, your example contains an error).  This is how to realize the "QBE" approach based on matching "$-names" with key names:

```
def matchName($name):
   first(.. | objects | to_entries[] | select(.key == $name) | .value) // null ;

def fillin($t):
  . as $in
  | $t
  | walk(if type == "string" and startswith("$")
         then .[1:] as $s | $in | matchName($s)
         else . end);
     
map(fillin(template))
```